# Webpack prod build stuck at 96% chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin

Tags: node.js, webpack

I am seeing this issue 100% of the attempts at building webpack for production.
I've tried the approach mentioned on the other similar StackOverflow issues which is `NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192`

my build command is:

```
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 rimraf build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config tools/webpack.prod.config.js -p --progress",
```

do you see perhaps an issue on how I am passing the options?
This build is executed on Travis, which is using Node version 8.14.0, unfortunately, I can't upgrade the version at the moment.

The error persists:

```
<s> [webpack.Progress] 96% [0] chunk asset optimization TerserPlugin

No output has been received in the last 10m0s, this potentially indicates a stalled build or something wrong with the build itself.
Check the details on how to adjust your build configuration on: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received

The build has been terminated
```

**An important detail is that on my localhost the build doesn't fail, on the CI it does fail 100% of the time.**

my package.json:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 rimraf build && cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config tools/webpack.prod.config.js -p",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/react-hooks": "3.1.5",
    "@atmedia/react-gpt": "2.1.1",
    "@babel/register": "7.10.1",
    "@optimizely/react-sdk": "2.0.1",
    "algoliasearch": "4.3.0",
    "alphanumeric-id": "1.0.1",
    "antd": "4.4.0",
    "apollo-boost": "0.4.7",
    "bluebird": "3.7.2",
    "body-parser": "1.19.0",
    "body-scroll-lock": "3.0.3",
    "browser-update": "3.3.19",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "compression": "1.7.4",
    "connected-react-router": "6.0.0",
    "copy-to-clipboard": "3.3.1",
    "core-js": "3.6.5",
    "crypto-js": "4.0.0",
    "date-fns": "2.14.0",
    "deep-assign": "3.0.0",
    "diff": "4.0.2",
    "draft-js": "0.11.6",
    "draft-js-linkify-plugin": "2.0.2",
    "draft-js-mention-plugin": "3.1.5",
    "draft-js-plugins-editor": "3.0.0",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "express-healthcheck": "0.1.0",
    "faker": "4.1.0",
    "filter-react-props": "0.0.4",
    "formik": "1.5.8",
    "foundation-sites": "6.5.3",
    "get-orientation": "1.1.2",
    "graphql": "15.1.0",
    "heapdump": "0.3.15",
    "history": "4.9.0",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "3.3.2",
    "https": "1.0.0",
    "ignore-styles": "5.0.1",
    "immutable": "3.8.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jstimezonedetect": "1.0.7",
    "jwt-decode": "2.2.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "make-error": "1.3.6",
    "moment": "2.26.0",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.31",
    "murmurhash3js": "^3.0.1",
    "nconf": "0.10.0",
    "newrelic": "6.9.0",
    "polished": "3.6.5",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "query-string": "6.13.1",
    "rc-progress": "3.0.0",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "15.6.2",
    "react-autosuggest": "10.0.2",
    "react-count-to": "0.12.0",
    "react-datepicker": "2.8.0",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-easy-crop": "3.0.1",
    "react-files": "2.4.8",
    "react-foundation": "0.9.6",
    "react-google-invisible-recaptcha": "0.2.11",
    "react-helmet": "6.1.0",
    "react-hot-loader": "4.12.21",
    "react-html-parser": "2.0.2",
    "react-input-mask": "2.0.4",
    "react-instantsearch-dom": "6.6.0",
    "react-intersection-observer": "8.26.2",
    "react-intl": "3.1.9",
    "react-loadable": "5.5.0",
    "react-markdown": "4.3.1",
    "react-modal": "3.11.2",
    "react-player": "1.15.0",
    "react-portal": "3.1.0",
    "react-rangeslider": "2.2.0",
    "react-redux": "7.2.0",
    "react-request": "3.1.2",
    "react-responsive": "8.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "4.3.1",
    "react-select": "3.1.0",
    "react-slider": "1.0.8",
    "react-tabs": "3.1.1",
    "react-tooltip": "4.2.7",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "5.1.1",
    "redux": "4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "3.0.6",
    "redux-promise-middleware": "6.1.2",
    "redux-storage": "4.1.2",
    "redux-storage-engine-localstorage": "1.1.4",
    "redux-thunk": "2.3.0",
    "regenerator-runtime": "0.13.5",
    "request": "2.88.2",
    "reselect": "4.0.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "4.0.0",
    "shortid": "2.2.15",
    "striptags": "3.1.1",
    "styled-components": "4.3.2",
    "universal-cookie": "4.0.3",
    "useragent": "2.3.0",
    "validator": "13.1.1",
    "web-video-player": "https://web-video-player.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/release/web-video-player-0.9.7-RC1.tgz",
    "window-or-global": "1.0.1",
    "xml": "1.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/core": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "7.5.2",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "7.5.2",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "7.5.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "7.5.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "7.2.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator": "7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.5.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.0.0",
    "@sambego/storybook-state": "1.3.6",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-backgrounds": "5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-centered": "5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-info": "5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-notes": "5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-storysource": "5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addon-viewport": "5.1.10",
    "@storybook/addons": "5.1.10",
    "@storybook/react": "5.1.10",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "10.0.6",
    "@testing-library/react-hooks": "2.0.1",
    "artillery": "1.6.0",
    "autoprefixer": "6.7.7",
    "babel-eslint": "10.0.2",
    "babel-jest": "25.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "2.3.0",
    "babel-plugin-lodash": "3.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "3.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "3.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.10.6",
    "babel-plugin-transform-imports": "1.5.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.24",
    "btoa": "1.2.1",
    "commander": "2.20.0",
    "cross-env": "5.2.0",
    "css-loader": "2.1.1",
    "enzyme": "3.10.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "1.14.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "3.4.0",
    "eslint": "5.16.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "17.1.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "13.2.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "5.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-babel": "3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-filenames-suffix": "1.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.35.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.18.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.14.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.7.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
    "fetch-mock": "8.0.0",
    "file-loader": "1.1.6",
    "flat": "2.0.1",
    "git-pre-hooks": "1.2.1",
    "glob": "7.1.4",
    "husky": "2.4.1",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "4.5.0",
    "imagemin-webp-webpack-plugin": "3.2.1",
    "jest": "25.1.0",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "2.1.0",
    "jest-css-modules-transform": "2.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "25.1.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom-global": "1.2.1",
    "jest-localstorage-mock": "2.4.0",
    "jest-styled-components": "6.3.3",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "lint-diff": "1.2.1",
    "lint-staged": "8.2.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.4",
    "mockdate": "2.0.5",
    "motion-ui": "2.0.3",
    "ncp": "2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "4.14.1",
    "node-sass-utils": "1.1.2",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "postcss-discard-duplicates": "2.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
    "postcss-loader": "2.0.10",
    "pre-commit": "1.2.2",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "react-storybook-addon-chapters": "3.1.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.3",
    "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.3",
    "sass-loader": "6.0.6",
    "sitemap-stream-parser": "1.7.0",
    "sqip": "0.3.3",
    "storybook-addon-intl": "2.4.1",
    "storybook-react-router": "1.0.5",
    "style-loader": "0.19.1",
    "stylelint": "9.10.1",
    "stylelint-config-recommended": "2.2.0",
    "stylelint-config-styled-components": "0.1.1",
    "stylelint-processor-styled-components": "1.8.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "1.4.1",
    "tmp": "0.0.33",
    "url": "0.11.0",
    "url-loader": "2.1.0",
    "webpack": "4.39.1",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.8.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.6",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "3.7.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.25.0",
    "webpack-manifest-plugin": "2.0.4",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.7.2"
  },
  "config": {
    "unsafe-perm": true
  },
}
```

any suggestions are highly appreciated

Comment: Your CI environment might not have enough memory to run the build, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your build takes longer than 10m without output this will happen.

You can use `travis_wait` to print something to the console each minute, as per the docs: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/common-build-problems/#build-times-out-because-no-output-was-received

Just `travis_wait {your_command}` and you should be good to go.

Be aware that your build taking longer than 10m could be a indicator of a more complicated underlying problem/freeze.